# 0 to the power of any number

Tags: proof-verification, exponentiation

I have proof that $0^n$ = undefined.

Since,
$2^5 = 32$,
$2^4 = 16$,
$2^5/2 = 32/2 = 16 = 2^4$.

Similarly if $0^n = 0$.

Then,
$0^{n-1} = 0$
$0^0/0 = 0/0 = 0^{n-1}$.

But $0/0$ is undefined.
Therefore $0^n = 0$.

But calculators give the result of $0^n$ as $0$. Can you explain where I am going wrong.

Comment: For $0^n$ see the answers below. But let me point out that your "proof" for $2^5=2^4$ also isn't correct.

Answer (score 3):

The rule $x^{n-1}=x^n/x$ requires that you divide by $x$, which you can't when $x=0$. The rule comes from 
$$
x^n=x^{n-1} x,
$$
and then dividing by $x$. But if $x$ is zero you cannot divide, and so the rule does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate $0^{n-1}$, you divided by $0$, which is undefined. Notice that $0^n=0\cdots0=0$ (with $n$ factors); there is no division involved here.